# Twilio Opt Out Overriding Server

Tags: twilio

My goal: 
To respond to help messages in a custom way from my Twilio NodeJS server I made.

Description:
I currently wrote my own NodeJS server to handle responding to messages for my business. It is a bit interactive/back and forth between the user and our service. However, I ran into a problem when I wanted to respond to "help" messages from the server. It seemed like whenever a user typed "help" to our number it was not hitting my server and therefore I couldn't respond to the message.

Instead Twilio would respond with a default message asking "do you want to unsubscribe?". So, to customize this message being sent back I made a twilio messaging service to handle opt out messages like "help", so I could customize the message. However, now my server gets NONE of the messages sent to my Twilio number. I think the messaging service has completely overriden my server. If I delete the service my server gets the texts fine.

How can I (from code if possible) override the "help" message of opt out. Let me know, and I appreciate you if you read this far. I am really struggling with this and it is eating up my time. Thanks again

Rob

Answer (score 0):

you cannot override help. You can use Advanced Opt-out which is attached to a Twilio Messaging Service to customize the help keyword responses, by updating it from the Twilio console.

[Customizing Users’ Opt-in and Opt-out Experience with Advanced Opt-Out](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/services/advanced-opt-out)

> Keeping track of your users' status With Advanced Opt-Out - you can
>   keep track of the most up-to-date information about your users' opt-in
>   and opt-out preferences. When an incoming message triggers one of your
>   opt-out keywords, Twilio includes an OptOutType property in the
>   request object sent to the webhook URL configured for your Messaging
>   Service. The value is START, STOP, or HELP, depending on the incoming
>   keyword.

[image]